# Apt upgrade failing keys

Tags: ubuntu

I am trying to update and upgrade my Ubuntu 20.04 virtual machine server but recently I started getting PUB_KEY not found error and when i looked up in the web, there were commands to recieve and I tried as many commands as I could with the key my logs were saying is missing but when i do it "keyserver.ubuntu.com" it says Key not found. Therefore I am unable to update, please any method to fix.

```
ubuntu@mighty:~$ sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade -y
Hit:1 https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu focal InRelease
Get:2 https://playit-cloud.github.io/ppa/data ./ InRelease [2086 B]
Ign:3 http://ppa.launchpad.net/certbot/certbot/ubuntu focal InRelease       Hit:4 http://ap-mumbai-1-ad-1.clouds.ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal InRelease
Hit:5 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal-security InRelease
Hit:6 http://ap-mumbai-1-ad-1.clouds.ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal-updates InRelease
Hit:7 http://ap-mumbai-1-ad-1.clouds.ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal-backports InRelease                                                            Get:8 http://deb.volian.org/volian scar InRelease [15.5 kB]
Ign:9 http://ppa.launchpad.net/jonathonf/ffmpeg-4/ubuntu focal InRelease
Err:8 http://deb.volian.org/volian scar InRelease
  The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY A87015F3DA22D980
Err:10 http://ppa.launchpad.net/certbot/certbot/ubuntu focal Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 185.125.190.52 80]
Hit:11 https://ngrok-agent.s3.amazonaws.com buster InRelease
Err:12 http://ppa.launchpad.net/jonathonf/ffmpeg-4/ubuntu focal Release       404  Not Found [IP: 185.125.190.52 80]
Reading package lists... Done
W: GPG error: http://deb.volian.org/volian scar InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY A87015F3DA22D980                                                        E: The repository 'http://deb.volian.org/volian scar InRelease' is not signed.                                                                          N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.                                                        N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.                                                                    E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/certbot/certbot/ubuntu focal Release' does not have a Release file.                                         N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.                                                        N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/jonathonf/ffmpeg-4/ubuntu focal Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
ubuntu@mighty:~$
```

This is an Oracle cloud Ubuntu virtual machine!

---

This is what I get when i try to add the missing PUB_KEY:

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys A87015F3DA22D980

-----

ubuntu@mighty:~$ sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys A87015F3DA22D980
Executing: /tmp/apt-key-gpghome.TUF52Pvtlo/gpg.1.sh --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys A87015F3DA22D980
gpg: keyserver receive failed: No data
ubuntu@mighty:~$
```

Comment: I have the same problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its resolved i basically renamed the ppa's to .bak in my system